# How to check if datagrid cell exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an if condition like:

```
if (e.Item.Cells[7].Text == "something")
```

But how can I check first if the **cell[7]** exists first?

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Cells.Count` property. If it's greater than 7 it means `Cells[7]` exists (since index is zero-based).

```
if (e.Item.Cells.Count > 7 && e.Item.Cells[7].Text == "something")
```